# How to implement search functionality based on calculated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

Some characteristics of my models' objects have to be calculated from its connections to other objects. For example, a template has_many orders. So the number of some template's orders can be considered as its popularity. I want my user to be able to sort templates based on their popularity. While I see storing orders number in DB somewhat redundant, I'm wondering how people solve such kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they use something called counter caches: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column